# Extracting a price using preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string that, from a file_get_contents() call, contains something like:

```
    <span class="cb_price_countdown cb_lot_price_1439066">$40.65</span>
```

And I would like the extract the price 40.65.  I am not familiar with regex or preg_match so I'm having a hard time.  So far I have tried:

```
    $pattern = "/\\\$?((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$/";
    preg_match ($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    print_r ($matches);
```

Which is not returning anything useful, and I've tried:

```
    $pattern = "/[\d+|\d+,\d+]\.\d{0,2}/";
```

but it's the same story.  Can somebody please tell me the correct preg_match pattern that I'm looking for?

Thank you,
Justin

Comment: don't use regular expressions for this. Don't steal content from other sites.

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this:

```
preg_match ( '/\$(\d+\.\d+)/', $subject, $matches );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
$str = '<span class="cb_price_countdown cb_lot_price_1439066">$40.65</span>';
preg_match('/<span[^>]*>\$(.*)<\/span>/', $str, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

yields:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(61) "$40.65<" [1]=> string(5) "40.65" }
```